# Flutter using TabBar inside Column instead of AppBar

Tags: flutter

in this below sample code, i want to have `Tab` into  `Column` not `AppBar` and when i run the app i get this error:

> Null check operator used on a null value

my code:

```dart
class Home144 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Text('Account Analysis'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Hello World'),

              DefaultTabController(
                length: 3,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 50),
                      child: TabBar(tabs: [
                        Tab(text: "Home"),
                        Tab(text: "Articles"),
                        Tab(text: "User"),
                      ]),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBarView(children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text("Home Body"),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text("Articles Body"),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text("User Body"),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Divider(color: Colors.black87),
            ],
          ).p(8.0),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: Change `ListView` to `Column`
Step 2: Use `Expanded` and `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text('Hello World'),
                Expanded(
                  child: DefaultTabController(
                    length: 3,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home144 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Text('Account Analysis'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text('Hello World'),
                Expanded(
                  child: DefaultTabController(
                    length: 3,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 50),
                          child: TabBar(tabs: [
                            Tab(text: "Home"),
                            Tab(text: "Articles"),
                            Tab(text: "User"),
                          ]),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TabBarView(children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Text("Home Body"),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Text("Articles Body"),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Text("User Body"),
                            ),
                          ]),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(color: Colors.black87),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Home144(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why i can't use in child of `body`?

Comment: To directly use ListView in body, you need to use Container to provide height https://googleflutter.com/flutter-listview-limit-height/ , with Column it's more easier to use Expanded to control child's height.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your appBar, just need to implement PreferredSizeWidget.

You are using tabs in the wrong way.

See this video for more information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POtoEH-5l40

And the documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs

This code may help you, but i really recommend reading the documentation.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Home144(),
    ));

class Home144 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: CustomTabBar(),
          body: TabBarView(children: [
            Container(
              child: Text("Home Body"),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("Articles Body"),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("User Body"),
            ),
          ])),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTabBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: preferredSize.height,
          child: TabBar(tabs: [
            Container(
              child: Text("Home Body"),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("Articles Body"),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("User Body"),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(40);
}
```

Comment: top of `TabBarView` i have multiple column and with this code i think i can't have